# MonoGame/OpenTK GLControl Widget in Windows Form using Xamarin

Tags: c#, opengl, xna, monogame, opentk

I'm trying to get MonoGame working in a windows form in Xaramin, but the key word here is in Xaramin as I have a custom Ribbon control working that is Cross Platform (working in Windows and Linux currently).

I was trying to port jaquadro's version from [here](http://jaquadro.com/2013/03/bringing-your-xna-winforms-controls-to-monogame-opengl/) but it's written for Visual Studio and it seems that Xaramin handles adding Custom controls differently.

I understand this might be as much a Xaramin question as a MonoGame one. I've googled and searched and scoured github, but haven't found a working version as of yet.

I'm assuming I'd have to make some sort of custom widget and add it as a

Thanks

RT

Comment: What exactly do you intend to use Xamarin for? Xamarin is a platform that enables you to create C# applications for iOS, Android, Mac, Linux and more. But it is unrelated to Windows Forms development. If you are trying to port a sort of "control" from one platform to another, the easiest would definitely be to create it in MonoGame.

Comment: I'm using Xamarin for cross platform development of a program which uses GTK# controls. Windows Forms is the wrong wording for me to use. I want to be able to use a MonoGame "canvas" so to speak in a GTK# GUI Program.